# display scroll bar for attributes under "shop by" in magento

Tags: magento, scrollbar

Under "shop by" . "category", "gender" ,"age group" "price", "manufacturer", "brand".

There are lot of attributes under "age group"

I want to apply a scroll box there , so i want to see only 6 values, if there is more values we have to use

"scroll bar" to see other attributes.

I want exactly like this:

http://www.snapdeal.com/products/mens-footwear-sports-shoes?

Please help me to find solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pure CSS.

```
max-height: 180px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
```

In my theme (Ultimo), i'm using the following for colors, however please mind that the below styling will only work on the last child and needs to be configured for your theme settings and layered navigation setup.

```
.block-layered-nav .block-content > dl > dd:last-child {
max-height: 180px;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Your example site is using a third party plugin which will work as well.